# Built in taxonomy categories.

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I made a taxonomy named "categories". Everything is working fine. after installing the plugin, I  need to  add categories. But I want 2 categories by default. That means when I  install the plugin there must show 2 categories under category taxonomy. Like this

--Front-page
--Single-page

these 2 categories  always show in the taxonomy box.

Looking for suggestions. Correct me if I use any term wrong.

Comment: Why would you create a custom taxonomy called `categories`?  That is very similar to the built in `category` taxonomy.  What's the point of duplicating it?

Comment: i am learning. It just a name. It could be genre, department etc.